# Cannot find a way to make tessnet2 work

Tags: c#, tesseract, object-recognition, tessnet2

I have created a console application.
Added a reference to tessnet2_32.

```
Ocr ocr = new Ocr();
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename))
{
    tessnet2.Tesseract tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
    tessocr.Init(@"C:\temp\tessdata", "eng", false);
...
```

I also tried changing `"C:\temp\tessdata"` to

```
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\tessdata
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\bin\debug
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\bin
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\bin\debug\tessdata
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\bin\tessdata
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\debug\tessdata
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\tessdata
C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\
```

The `tessdata` folder itself contained 9 failed and was added to all of these locations:

```
eng.cube.bigrams
eng.cube.fold
eng.cube.lm
eng.cube.bigrams
eng.cube.params
eng.cube.size
eng.cube.word-freq
eng.tesseract_cube.nn
eng.traineddata
```

But it just always exists at that .Init line with a message:

```
The file 'z:\dev\interne\cs\tesseract-ocr-svn\dotnet\tessnet2.cpp' does not exist.
```

I cannot imagine why it is trying to access some Z disk while I only have C. Or I just completely misunderstand the error.

Can someone be kind enough to post step by step telling what to do and/or what I am doing wrong? I feel completely lost even after reading 30+ google links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong version of language data file; what you have is for Tesseract 3.0x. tessnet2 is .NET wrapper for Tesseract 2.04, so you will need to load compatible data file.

Try download tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/.

Comment: It would have taken me at least 36 days and 17 hours more to realize that. Thanks so much, it worked! :))