# Tessnet2 where download arabic language

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

I want to grab numbers in Arabic language using with :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696537/How-to-use-Tessnet2-library
I installed Tessnet2 using with NuGet packages & created a console application & for English language it works very well.
Now the problem is Arabic language!
Where i can i download Arabic language?

---

See these related topics:

1. [Recognize numbers in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411893/recognize-numbers-in-images)
2. [Tesseract 3.0 OCR .NET 4.0 Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659278/tesseract-3-0-ocr-net-4-0-wrapper)
3. [Cannot find a way to make tessnet2 work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067651/cannot-find-a-way-to-make-tessnet2-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract 2.0x, which tessnet2 is a wrapper for, does not support Arabic. You would need Tesseract 3.0x; try this [.NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) ([nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/)) with compatible 3.0x [tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr).